# how to delete a newline char from a StringBuffer? the blow func reads from a file then stores in a Stringbuffer

Tags: java

This function read from a file and store in a `string(input)` then store input in a `Stringbuffer (textfile)`. then prints textfile
for example: `file= ab` , after the print statment : `a newline b`

any suggestions how can i fix this?

```
 StringBuffer textfile = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer decodedfile=new StringBuffer();
            String output;

            String input = "";
            int i;
            FileInputStream fin;
            FileOutputStream fout;

            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);   // open input file
            fout = new FileOutputStream(args[1]); // open output file

            do {
                    i = fin.read();

                    if (((char) i != ' ') && (i != -1)&&((char)i!='\n')) {
                        input += (char) i;

                    }
                } while (i != -1);
            input=input.replace('\n', '.');


            for(int j=0;j<input.length();j++)   // fill textfile
            {
                textfile.append(input.charAt(j));
            }
           for(int j=0;j<textfile.length();j++) // test output
           {
               System.out.println(textfile.charAt(j));
           }
```

Comment: input: ab           output: a newline b

Answer (score 1):

You are using `println` each time you print, this will print each `char` and then add a new line character at the end.

Just change the `System.out.println(textfile.charAt(j));` to:

```
System.out.print(textfile.charAt(j));
```